# Ellipses when converting list of numpy arrays to string in python 3

Tags: python, numpy, ellipsis

I have a list of numpy arrays.  I want to convert the list of arrays to a string.  So that there will be a long string of arrays like '[ stuff ], [ stuff2 ]', etc.  Each array has 192 elements.  Conversion works when I do str(myList) if the list has 5 arrays or less.  If it has 6 arrays, I get back truncated arrays with ellipses.  Why is this?  How can I stop it?.

I have examined the arrays themselves and they do not in fact contain ellipses, they contain the correct values.

I further looked into it and if I do something like str(myList[0:5]) it works on the first 5 arrays, but that 6th array always goes to ellipses. Note that this is not just ellipses when printing to screen either, I'm saving this variable and when I look at the saved text it has the ellipses.

Comment: Sounds like your list of arrays is really a 2d array.  `numpy` uses ellipses when arrays get larger than a 1000 elements (hence the 5 v 6).  If it was really a list of arrays, it would format each one independently, and not use ellipses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a quick look, the only way is to use numpy.set_printoptions:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(5, size=(6, 192))
s1 = str(a)
np.set_printoptions(threshold = np.prod(a.shape))
s2 = str(a)

print('...' in s1)
print('...' in s2)
```

gives

```
True
False
```

on my Ubuntu 14.04 system, Python 2.7, Numpy 1.8.2

I would restore the default to 1000 after changing it, and, in my
opinion, the function numpy.array2string should have a threshold
argument.